# How to update postgresql version to 11 in embedded "ru.yandex.qatools.embed"?

Tags: java, postgresql

I am using this ru.yandex.qatools.embed for integration test in spring boot. Right now having "database.embedded.postgresql.version=V9_6_3.
Want to update to 11 for procedure suppor. How to update it for version 11.

Comment: May include what you have tried and the issues you are facing?

Comment: You can't because "Note: this project is not being actively maintained anymore" https://github.com/yandex-qatools/postgresql-embedded

Comment: Thanks Simon, this will help me